# Formulário não envia as mensagens

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um formulário em bootstrap do qual estou usando o jquery para fazer o disparo. Estou usando o seguinte código:

**Formulário**

```
 <form class="contact-form" name="contact-form"  method="post">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nome</label>
                                <input type="text" id="Nome" name="Nome" class="form-control" required="required" style="border-color: #f00">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" required="required" style="border-color: #f00">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Telefone</label>
                                <input type="Telefone" id="Telefone" class="form-control" style="border-color: #245269">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Empresa</label>
                                <input type="text" id="Empresa" name="Empresa" class="form-control" style="border-color: #245269">
                            </div>                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Assunto</label>
                                <select name="Assunto" id="Assunto" class="form-control" required="required" style="border-color: #f00">
                                    <option value="selecione">Selecione</option>
                                    <option value="Orçamento">Orçamento</option>
                                    <option value="Dúvidas">Dúvidas</option>
                                    <option value="Financeiro">Financeiro</option>
                                    <option value="Outro Assunto">Outro Assunto</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Messagem</label>
                                <textarea name="Messagem" id="messagem" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" style="border-color: #f00"></textarea>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="button" id="enviar" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Enviar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
        $("#enviar").on("click", function () {
            var Nome = $("#Nome").val();
            var Email = $("#Email").val();
            var Telefone = $("#Telefone").val();
            var Empresa = $("#Empresa").val();
            var Assunto = $("#Assunto").val();
            var Mensagem = $("#Mensagem").val();
            $.post("enviar.php", {
                Nome: Nome,
                Email: Email,
                Telefone: Telefone,
                Empresa: Empresa,
                Assunto: Assunto,
                Mensagem: Mensagem
            }, function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                });
                $("#Nome").val('');
                $("#Email").val('');
                $("#Telefone").val('');
                $("#Empresa").val('');
                $("#Assunto").val('');
                $("#Mensagem").val('');
            });
        });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
    /*    ini_set('display_errors',1);
        ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
      */  
        $nomeUsuario = trim($_POST['Nome']);
        $emailUsuario = trim($_POST['Email']);
        $telefoneUsuario = trim($_POST['Telefone']);
        $empresaUsuario = trim($_POST['Empresa']);
        $assuntoUsuario = trim($_POST['Assunto']);
        $mensagemUsuario = trim($_POST['Mensagem']);    
            $telUsuario = (empty($telefoneUsuario))?('Não informado'):($telefoneUsuario);
            $empUsuario = (empty($empresaUsuario))?('Não informado'):($empresaUsuario);

            include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
            $mail = new PHPMailer();

          $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.sitecliente.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'falecom@sitecliente.com';
$mail->Password = 'senha';
            $mail->AddAddress("email@cliente.com");
            $mail->From = $emailUsuario;
            $mail->FromName = "Mensagem enviada pelo Fale Conosco";
            $mail->AddReplyTo($emailUsuario, $mail->FromName);
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $data = date("d/m/Y");
            $hora = date("H:i");

            $mensagemHTML = "<div align='justify'>";
            $mensagemHTML .= "<div style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\">Mensagem enviada <strong> no dia ".$data." &agrave;s ".$hora."</strong> </div><br><br>";
            $mensagemHTML .= "<div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"><strong>Nome:</strong></font><div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"> " .utf8_decode($nomeUsuario)."</div><br>";
            $mensagemHTML .= "<div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"><strong>E-mail:</strong></div><div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"> " .utf8_decode($emailUsuario)."</div><br>";
            $mensagemHTML .= "<div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"><strong>Telefone:</strong></div><div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"> " .utf8_decode($telUsuario)."</div><br>";
            $mensagemHTML .= "<div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"><strong>Empresa:</strong></div><div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"> " .utf8_decode($empUsuario)."</div><br>";
            $mensagemHTML .= "<div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"><strong>Assunto:</strong></div><div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"> " .utf8_decode($assuntoUsuario)."</div><br>";
            $mensagemHTML .= "<div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"><strong>Mensagem:</strong></div><div color=#000000 style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family:Tahoma;\"> " .utf8_decode($mensagemUsuario)."</div><br>";
            $mensagemHTML .= "<\div>";

            $mail->Subject = "Mensagem do site";
            $mail->Body = $mensagemHTML;
            $mail->Send();
```

O meu objetivo é que ao enviar a mensagem, apareça o modal do bootstrap. Só que nao envia. Parece ter algum erro que nao estou conseguindo identificar. Outro problema é que antes a validação funcionava, depois que coloquei o jquery, ele mostra o modal sem validar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca um `ID` no seu `form`:

`<form class="contact-form" name="contact-form"  method="post" id="form-contact">`

Nunca mais faça uma lista de campos em JavaScript para enviar um `form`. Existem maneiras mais dinâmicas, usando o `serialize`, por exemplo.

```
$(function() {
    $("#enviar").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'enviar.php',
            data: $("#form-contact").serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Veja no **Inspect Element** se mostra algum erro. Acho que pode ser algo a ver com sua *URL*.

Comment: Olá Tao. Obrigado pela ajuda. Porém percebi que o problema pode estar no arquivo PHP, do qual editei colocando para aparecer erros tratados. Quando tento executar diretamente via post, não aparece o erro, mas aparece a página "
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.". É estranho, pois o cliente está na Locaweb e quando criei um arquivo phpinfo() para ver se o servidor dele dá suporte, aparece que dá suporte sim.

Comment: Editei o meu código e comentei a linha $mail->IsSMTP(); Funcionou na Infolink, porém na locaweb continua dando o erro 500